# Can there be a different proof for: "If $N$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ of index $2$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$"?

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

For a proof of the following theorem, I am wondering if it can be modified in the beginning steps so that it is the same for the proof of Lagrange's theorem.

> Theorem: If $N$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ of index $2$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

It is in the beginning portion of the proof that I have some questions.  The beginning of the proof I have in mind goes as follows:

> "Let $a\in G$, since $[G:N]=2$, then there are two cosets of $G$.  So we can further assume that $a\notin N$, hence $aN\neq N$ and so $N\cap aN=\emptyset$..."

Instead of having $N\cap aN=\emptyset$, can't we have $aN\cap bN=\emptyset$ where $a, b\in G$ and $a\neq b$, and would the proof still work.  The reason I ask is that in the proof of Lagrange theorem, if given a finite group of order $n$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $k$ then $|H|\mid |G|$.  In the proof of Lagrange theorem, we can decompose $G$ into the union of its disjoint $k$ cosets:  $G=a_1H \cup a_2H \cup \dots \cup a_kH$ and $H$ mpas bijectively to each $a_iH$ for $i=1,2,\dots k$, we also have   $|G|=|a_1H|+|a_2H|+\dots+|a_kH|$.

Applying the same type of reasoning to the theorem, if $a\notin N$, then since $[G:N]=2$, then don't we have $G=aN \cup bN$ with $a\neq b$, $aN\cap bN=\emptyset$, and $|G|=|aN|+|bN|$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I will say the same thing I did in your previous question: $$nN=N$$ for all $n\in N$.

Comment: There are two cosets. One of them is $N$; and $N=bN$ if and only if $b\in N$. The other coset is given by $aN$ for *any* $a\notin N$ (since $aN=N$ if and only if $a\in N$,, hence $aN\neq N$ if and only if $a\notin N$). Not sure why you want to call it $b$; call it $e$ if you want.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for the clarification

Comment: Take the action of $G$ on the cosets of $N$ by right multiplication. This is a homomorphism from $G$ to the symmetric group $S_2$, the kernel is $N$ (since stabilizing one point of two also stabilizes the other, But kernels are normal subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[G:N]=2$, there is exactly two cosets of $N$ in $G$. One of them must be $eN=N.$ We have

$$n\in N\iff nN=N.$$

(Can you prove this?)

This is equivalent to

$$a\notin N\iff aN\neq N.$$

If $b\neq a$, $a\notin N$, and $aN\cup bN=G$, then, since cosets are disjoint, we must have $b\in N$, so that $bN$ is simply $N$. This holds for any such $b$; therefore, there is no loss of generality in assuming $b=e$, in which case we are back to your first proof of the theorem in question.

Comment: I thought since the cosets are disjoint, it doesn't really matter if it is $N$ or $bN$ where $b\neq a$.  Thank you for the write up clarification.